# I Can see topic in rostopic list but cannot echo

Tags: matlab, ros, simulink

I'm trying to connect a Duckiebot with ROS to MATLAB Simulink (unfortunately, I'm compelled to use them), and something strange is happening. I can ping both devices, and I can also send commands from MATLAB to the robot. The problem is that MATLAB/Simulink is not able to receive messages from the robot. I've tried various guides ( like this https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119559-why-is-the-ros-subscriber-callback-in-matlab-not-triggered-when-messages-are-published-from-an-exter ) on the internet, but it's not working. Do you know how to resolve this issue?
( i also tried editing the \etc\host on the robot, even though when i reboot it i can't see the changes but it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issues when trying to connect to a remote ROS master. I've had it myself so often that I ended up writing a Gist for it:
https://gist.github.com/chfritz/8c2adab45a94e091be77c55b0432ad2e

Look in particular at the troubleshooting below. The issue is usually to do with the way ROS_HOSTNAME is set on all participating devices.

Comment: This gist is only 18 lines long, it would be nice to include the code directly in your answer so that it's self-contained. Albeit github is unlikely to result in a dead link any time soon.

Comment: thk for you answer i've tried seting ROS_IP IN the  ~/.bashrc file but it's still not working, but the same bot on a MacBook works

Comment: Also if i try to run  getenv('ROS_MASTER_URI') from matlab i get: 

ans =

    'http://192.168.244.156:11311'
that actually the right ip

Comment: What did you set for ROS_HOSTNAME? Did you follow the troubleshooting guide at the bottom? It is important that every participant can look up each other participant under the ROS_HOSTNAME those others use when they announce themselves to the ROS master.

Comment: @Wolfie Normally I would agree, but most of the value is actually not the Gist-code itself but the troubleshooting guide below, which is a bit longer.

Comment: @ChristianFritz  my configuration is this one: i have my windows pc with matlab and my IP is 192.168.244.161. Then I have my robot and it's IP is: ( I do hostname -i on the ssh and I get my IP

Comment: @ChristianFritz i have windows pc+matlab with IP:  192.168.244.161. then a robot with IP : 192.168.244.156 ( I do hostname -I to get it on the ssh)   on the robot I edited the ~/.bashrc file and I've added this three line at the end: 
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.244.156
export ROS_IP=192.168.244.156                                                                                               export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.244.156:11311    then on matlab when I start I do : setenv('ROS_MASTER_URI','http://192.168.244.156:11311')
 setenv('ROS_IP','192.168.244.161') but is not working

Comment: and i can actually send msg to the robot.. but still can't receive them

Comment: ah and the strange thing is that 1 in 100 run it can read them.. but If i run them again it stop. i tried on a MacBook and it worked perfectly every time

Comment: you also need to set the ROS_HOSTNAME on the pc

Comment: @ChristianFritz i've tried with ubuntu an mac os and it's working perfectly. Triedo on 3 other windows PC with same config and not working there is probably some config problem with winodws